# Why setState(contains another setState inside) after promise be called twice?

Tags: reactjs

Why setState(contains another setState inside) after promise be called twice?

Demo code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-issue-v1fpv

```
const App = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  const onClick = async () => {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r));
    // when after promise, setB called twice
    // remove promise, setB called once

    setB((prevB) => {
      console.log("setB");

      setA((prevA) => prevA + 1);
      return prevB + 1;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {a} | {b} | <button onClick={onClick}>+1</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why are you using impure state updater functions? Please try to include code a properly formatted code snippets and not as an image. Images are more difficult to read and they aren't searchable.

Comment: It's a very interesting question. I suspect it's because during a functional update, there is a state change (setA), React retriggers the functional update callback for the setB, even if b didn't change to be sure that the setB gets the newest value.

Answer (score 1):

For those who also confused, here is the answer from React docs:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to
>   **setState)**
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer Note:
>
> This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be
> double-invoked in production mode.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21114#issuecomment-808697394